# What file is needed for Make Command when trying to build a netbeans project with MinGW?

Tags: netbeans, mingw

I am fairly new to programming and was using this tutorial to set up SDL: http://blog.housmous.com/2012/01/setting-up-sdl-and-netbeans-on-windows-7/

I followed each step carefully and got to the point where I needed to build the application (part 7) when I got a resolve missing native build tools pop up:    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/caWos.png)

Does anyone know what file is needed for make command to make everything work smoothly? I assume it is one of the many in the same bin file as the others?

Any help /explanations would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Thanks for helping me through this user greatwolf. After adding mingw32-make.exe I got an error saying

"mingw32-make is incompatible and is not supported. Use make from MSYS".

As far as I can tell a MSYS-make.exe file or anything similar was not included in the mingw install.

Does anybody know where I can get this file?

Comment: `mingw32-make.exe` is the gnu make tool included with mingw install.

Comment: You should use `c:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe` .

Answer (score 0):

MinGW make is not supported. Go to  MinGW Installation Manager. Under All Packages, choose MSYS, and click MSYS make. Apply changes. Now you have MSYS make installed.